# Pass parameter from viewmodels to another

Tags: c#, mvvm

When I searched,I found,how to bind values from viewmodel to view but not viewmodel to viewmodel.can anyone help me to do that. what i need is to pass Authentication to other viewmodel.I am new in the MVVM world so please give me more detail.
my ViewModel look like this

```
public class ModelView_Authentication : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Binding authentication
    private Authentication _authentication;

    public Authentication authentication
    {
        get { return _authentication; }

        set
        {
            _authentication = value;
            NotifayPropertyChanged("_authentication");
        }
    }
    
    //Command Button
    public ModelView_Authentication()
    {
        authentication = new Authentication();
        ButtonCommand = new ViewModdelCommand(exeMethode, canexeMethode);
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool canexeMethode(Object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //run this Command Onclick Button
    private void exeMethode(Object param)
    {
       
    }

    protected void NotifayPropertyChanged(string s)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(s));
        }
    }

    //Run Assync Login 
    public static async Task<string> main(Authentication authentication)
    {
        var tocken = await Login.GetConnection(authentication);
        return tocken.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Viewmodels can freely access each other (or store result in shared model), provided there are references. Simply make reference available, there are at least 100 ways of how to pass reference.

Comment: @Sinatr can u tell me just a one way

Comment: I'd create a model to handle user authentication, user switching, etc. Then both viewmodels need access to it, one to set a state, preferably via model validate method and another to e.g. read user rights. The simplest is to make model instance available as `App` property.

Comment: @Sinatr can we talk in Privat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need is to pass Authentication to other viewmodel

Your main ViewModel adheres to `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can have your other VMs subscribe to the notification process of the main VM and acquire changes to specific properties as needed.

---

Just have a reference to the main VM, it is as easy as that. Where the VMs get their references, that process is up to you.

A good place is on `App` class. Since the `App` class is known throughout each of the namespaces, setup up a static property on it, set it after the main VM is created, and then access the it as needed.

```
public static ModelView_Authentication AuthVM { get; set; }
```

the access such as

```
var mainVM = App.AuthVM;
```